# Parse-server social login

Tags: javascript, parse-server, google-signin

I am developing application based on Parse-server and I want to offer social login. I found this guide in the documentation http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#linking-users.

I started to implement the social login by google. I did following steps:

1) I added following lines to the ParseServer settings

```
var api = new ParseServer({
...
    auth:{
        google: {}
    },
...
});
```

2) I did the authentication by hello.js on the client side (call user._linkWith function on login)

```
hello.init({
  google: 'My Google id'
});

hello.on('auth.login', function(auth) {
  // Call user information, for the given network
  hello(auth.network).api('me').then(function(r) {
    const user = new Parse.User();
    user._linkWith(auth.network, auth.authResponse).then(function(user){
      console.log('You are logged in successfully.');
    });
  });
});
```

When I debugged it, I found that it fails in **_linkWith()**  function, when provider object is preparing. Object AuthProviders, which should store all providers, is empty. Because of it the statement **provider = authProviders['google'];** leads to undefined. Invoking **provider.authenticate(...);** leads to error "Cannot read property 'authenticate' of undefined"

What am I missing or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for all your answers.

Honza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you register the authenticationProvider? You can find examples in our unit tests on how to do so:

https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/5813fd0bf8350a97d529e5e608e7620b2b65fd0c/spec/AuthenticationAdapters.spec.js#L139

Comment: It seems (contrary to the Parse JS guide's examples) that options can have an "authData" field with "id" and credentials nested inside it. If not, this answer applies. I managed to find an example for Facebook in the bundled FacebookUtils, see https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-JS/blob/master/src/FacebookUtils.js Is there something similar for other third-party authentication providers? The Parse Server JavaScript guide completely fails to mention authenticationProvider registration.

Answer (score 1):

I also got this error and looked at the _linkWith(provider, options) source code. It checks if `options` has an `authData` field (which in turn should contain `id` and credentials). If so, it uses `options.authData`. Otherwise it falls back on looking up a previously registered authentication provider mentioned in the previous answer.

This is a fragment of the code I'm using:

```
const authData = {
    "id": profile.getId(),
    "id_token": id_token
}
const options = {
    "authData": authData
}
const user = new Parse.User();
user._linkWith('google', options).then(function(user) {
    console.log('Successful user._linkWith(). returned user=' + JSON.stringify(user))
}, function(error) {
    console.log('Error linking/creating user: ' + error)
    alert('Error linking/creating user: ' + error)
    // TODO handle error
})
```